# How do you add a Trend Line to a Graph in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, arcgis-10.6, graph

[image: A graph having a trend line]

I can't seem to be able to get a trendline into my graph. what is the best possible way to get this done?

Comment: Have you looked at the ArcGIS help page: [Adding a function line to a graph](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/graphs/adding-a-function-line-to-a-graph.htm)?

Comment: let me do that .

Comment: tanks it worked

Comment: Great! Please add your solution as an answer so that it can help others.